# CORS error when trying to fetch linkedIn https://api.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken API from Front-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, linkedin-api

Access to fetch at 'https://api.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken' from origin 'http://localhost:4000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoUQ0.png)

I have added "proxy":"https://api.linkedin.com/" to package.json file and removed it from the endPoint where  fetching the API. After deployment, receiving a 200 status code from the accessToken API, but the response contains an error message stating, "you have to enable JavaScript to run the app."

Thank you

Comment: Please add the request.